# Can I have a list of all hyperref links at the end of the document for printing (similar to references written in plain text)

Tags: hyperref, pdf, printing

I use the hyperref package a lot and it creates beautiful document. But I want to make sure that those links are still usable when people print the document.

So I would like to include a listoflinks similar to a bibliography: A list with link titles, the page where it appears, and the URL it points to.

Is there already a package or option for that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Something \href{http://interesting.example.com}{interesting}!
% \listoflinks
\end{document}
```

In a generated PDF I can now click the "interesting", but if someone prints the document, the link information is lost, so I would like to see at `\listoflinks` something like

- interesting, 1, http://interesting.example.com

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `J$` on mastodon.nl I now have a clean solution:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listlinksname}{List of Links}
\newlistof{links}{lnks}{\listlinksname}
\let\oldhref\href
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\oldhref{#1}{#2}\addcontentsline{lnks}{figure}{#2: \url{#1}}}
\usepackage{xurl}\urlstyle{same}\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{\newline}

\begin{document}
Something \href{http://interesting.example.com}{interesting}!

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listlinksname}\listoflinks
\end{document}
```

You can see the full code in the source: [https://hg.sr.ht/~arnebab/draketo/browse/software/guile-10x.org?rev=32fd75f73f0a#L10](https://hg.sr.ht/%7Earnebab/draketo/browse/software/guile-10x.org?rev=32fd75f73f0a#L10)

Resulting PDF: https://www.draketo.de/software/guile-10x.pdf

HTML: https://www.draketo.de/software/guile-10x

Comment: you need to be careful with the content of the url if you redefine \href list that, things like `#` and `%` in an url won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your hint! Do you know a safer way?

Comment: I would probably put the url in a bib-file and then setup something with biblatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I thought about bibtex, but the use-case is having links exported in LaTeX that are also exported to plain links in HTML from the same document. I just did a quick experiment and found that escaping # and % is already taken care of by exporting from Emacs org-mode. So thank you for the warning — but I got lucky that it doesn’t hurt for my usecase.